# How does C protect pointer memory?

Tags: c, pointers, memory, memory-management

Given:

```
int a = 1;
int *p = &a;
int b = -1;
*++p = 2;
```

Is there anything that prevents b from being over written from -1 to 2 if in the apparently not unlikely event the two a and b were written next to each other in memory?

Comment: C does not guarantee any memory protection. That is why this is called *undefined behaviour*.

Comment: Bottom line is segfault, that protects *other* processes. *"in the unlikely event the two a and b were written next to each other in memory?"* You'll be overwriting **something**.

Comment: @WeatherVane: This is not required by the standard. Most CPUs do not even have such protection.

Comment: @WeatherVane That's a generally feature of the OS, not C, and is absolutely not required by the language specification.

Comment: @Bren Did you try compiling and running this code? How about under [`valgrind()`](http://valgrind.org/)?

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant IMO a program not compiling or running is a comparatively fortunate failure mode (of poor memory management) compared to mysterious occasional crashes, silent data corruption, security holes, etc.

Comment: @Olaf that's what I was trying to say, that some OS do have memory protection for other processes.

Comment: @IskarJarak what I meant is that OP will be over writing something, unless the OS is protecting another process.

Comment: @WeatherVane Oh, right, sorry. From my reading of your comment it wasn't 100% clear that you knew segmentation faults are protection that is unrelated to C itself.

Comment: @WeatherVane: Ok, just wondered, as I presumed from other postings you do know better.

Comment: @IskarJarak yes, it is. I didn't assert the converse, did I.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant I just thought it was worth explicitly mentioning for the benefit of others.

Comment: @IskarJarak I didn't know valgrind existed and I was't sure if running the code would really tell me much as I don't know how C manages memory (is it different on different implementations, is it consistent, etc. ). I'm just learning C for the first time going though K&R only done web programming before this.

Comment: @Bren You should definitely learn to use valgrind, it's a pretty handy tool for working with C. As for *"implementations"* (in C, this just means compiler version + stdlib implementation), compiling and running would at least have told you how one implementation behaved, and then you could have asked/searched if that was standard compliant (C has a formal standard, unlike e.g. Ruby) . For future reference, C generally offers little or no protection of any kind, and *"try it and see what it does"* is an approach that will typically lead to better questions.

Comment: @Bren Also, I don't know what compiler you're using, but I thoroughly recommend finding the appropriate warning and debug flags (for gcc or clang, `-W -Wall -std=c99 -pedantic -g` would be a good start although since you're working through K&R you might want to use `-std=c89` instead.

Comment: When you try things, though, best to use valgrind - code that compiles and appears to run may not really be valid.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you meant the last line to be `*++p = 2`, no, there's nothing that protects pointer memory.  Modifying a pointer to point outside the object it (originally) points to and then dereferencing it results in undefined behavior, and anything might happen.

In the code as written, `*(a++)` applies the dereference operator to a non-pointer type, which is a constraint violation, so is required to produce a compile time diagnostic and not compile...

Comment: yeah incrementing p is what I meant.

Answer (score 9):

> How does C protect pointer memory?

It doesn't.

> Is there anything that prevents b from being over written from -1 to 2
>   if in the unlikely event the two a and b were written next to each
>   other in memory?

No.

And the two variables being "next to each other in memory" isn't unlikely at all.

C give you the power to cause a lot of problems it you're not careful.

Answer (score 1):

```
*++p = 2;
```

C says it is invalid and the statement invokes undefined behavior. A compiler is allowed to stop translation with an error if it detects it but there is no requirement from C to do detect this kind of errors (which are actually really hard to detect).

Comment: That was a typo fixed the question.

Comment: @Bren you meant `*++p` and not `*(p++)`.

Comment: Thanks, didn't realize that would make a difference, back to K&R for me.

Comment: Was the same in K&R, me thinks.

Comment: On the other hand, I doubt this is really undefined behavior. Pointer arithmetic is defined behavior. The computation of the resulting address of the increment is defined and to that address the int value 2 is written. What is not defined is what will happen due to that. For sure, it would be a compiler bug if it refused to translate pointer arithmetic operations.

Comment: @BitTickler first writing to an invalid object is undefined behavior, second in the range of possible undefined behaviors the Standard explicitly mentions terminating the translation. If there is something you didn't understand, feel free to ask a new question.

Comment: @BitTickler It could be undefined behavior just as `p[2] = 2` could but it's not by itself. I don't think it's invalid syntax either, it's just really bad style..

Comment: Downvoter, care to explain  the downvote? Do you also think undefined behavior does not give latitude to the compiler to stop the translation?...

Comment: @iharob It is clearly invalid in the context of the question (`int a=1; int* p = &a;`), and usually I would expect an answer to share the context of the question, although @oauh could have been clearer about that.

Comment: @IskarJarak It's natural from a programmer to expect that, hence I am deleting my comments.

Comment: The compiler has no right and no means to stop compiling if it sees pointer arithmetics. As it has no facilities to bounds check either (all those MSVC bound checks are extras not standard functionality of a C- compiler), it would either a) check whenever it sees pointer arithmetics (which would be nonsense) or b) it won't stop when it sees it. As it does not have any notion of analysing if the pointer arithmetic expression is in bounds or just random numbers, it has no criteria to abort compilation. If YOU fail to understand what a C-compiler does, feel free to ask lol

Comment: "I doubt this is really undefined behavior." -- All the worse for you. Try familiarizing yourself with the C language. "Pointer arithmetic is defined behavior." -- This is both wrong and irrelevant. "The compiler has no right and no means to stop compiling if it sees pointer arithmetics." -- Wrong again. "If YOU fail to understand what a C-compiler does, feel free to ask lol " -- you're the last person anyone should ask.

Answer (score 1):

No, nothing would stop you in doing that. Pointer arithmetic is well defined, this means that you can move your pointer in any direction to point to another location. But with this setting, you can't be certain that which memory are you actually modifying. Because during compilation, optimizers could move your variable to a different location.

As in your case, assuming everything is streamlined and straight. Your order of declaring variables are a, p, and b. Let's say (a and b) gets x and p gets y bytes of memory depending upon your machine architecture and OS.

Your memory should look like:

```
  ________ __________________
 | (a) x  | (p) y   | (b) x  |
 |________|_________|________|
```

which means that, ++p would evaluate to p + sizeof(p). If 'p' is pointing to start of 'a' then this means that incrementing it by (y) bytes would leave 'p' in 'y' memory region (assuming y >= x) or in 'x' otherwise. So you are actually modifying the p's memory itself not b's.

P.S: Power provided by C should be best left to experienced C programmers.

Comment: "Pointer arithmetic is well defined" -- Not If the arithmetic results in a pointer that is outside the bounds (+1) of the object pointed to by the original pointer ... the resulting value is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

If you place `a`, `b` variables into separate pages (say, using `mmap`), then `mprotect` call can be used to set `PROT_READ` protection on the page that contains the variable `b`.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, `b` may likely be overwritten.

For me, using `GDB` I get that both variables are placed after each other in memory:

```
(gdb) x &a
0xffffcb80: 0x00000001
(gdb) x &b
0xffffcb84: 0x00000002
```

However, this is not guaranteed.

Since incrementing an `int *` increases its address by `sizeof(int)` we reach the next `int` which for me contains `b` already.

The code...

```
int a = 1;
int *p = &a;
int b = -1;
*++p = 2;
printf("b: %i\n", b);
```

therefore prints:

```
b: 2
```

`C` has no memory protection for its own process memory. You can write code like this but you may run into trouble: As soon as you increment your `int *` you cause `undefined behavior` because you leave the variable's actual size. You should never make assumptions about variable locations like this because it might not hold true so anything could happen and you won't like the instability it brings.